# Why aren't triangle congruency rules ASA and AAS just combined?

Tags: geometry

AAS says "Any two angles and a non-included side" while

ASA says "Any two angles and the included side".

That's just "any two angles and *a* side"?  Why do we have both the AAS and ASA rules for triangle congruency?

Answer (score 4):

AAS, unlike ASA, is not universal when you consider  non-Euclidean geometries.

Imagine the Earth is a sphere.  Draw the meridian from the North Pole $N$ through London $L$ to the South Pole $S$.  Construct the great circle perpendicular to $NLS$ through $L$, drawing this route westwards until it meets the Equator at point $M$ west of South America.  Then you construct median $NMS$.

You now have two triangles $LMN$ and $LMS$ that satisfy AAS, as each triangle has two right angles and a common side not between the right angles.  But the third angles are different because London is not on the Equator, so the triangles are not congruent.

The Greeks used geometry and trigonometry to model the  Earth and sky as well as an idealized plane, so the failure of AAS on spheres was a big deal.

Comment: I could use a picture.  Having trouble visualising this...

Answer (score 0):

That's to help you remember that SAS and SSA are different.

Comment: But they aren't... only in spelling :)  The rule really should be "any two angles and any one side".

Comment: They are different. SAS works and SSA does not.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.  You're talking about SAS and SSA.  I'm talking about AAS and ASA.  Therefore your answer doesn't seem to apply.  If it does, please elaborate by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, because of “the angle sum of triangle”, they can be combined into just only one (ASA, say). But then some one probably will raise the following question:–

From the AAS situation – a not-yet-congruent state, why do I have to write one more step (saying the equality of the third A via “the angle sum of triangle”)  to claim the congruency by the only ASA, when the situation is so obvious?